# Unity My Replay Script not working?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Recently, I am working on a roller ball game ( just for education purpose). And mainly I am working on replay script. That means as long as I click replay button, player previous movement shall be known. It was supposed to be similar to prince of persia rewind feature. But I have done something wrong.

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityStandardAssets.CrossPlatformInput;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    private const int buffersize = 1000;
    private MyKeyFrame[] playerskeyframe = new MyKeyFrame [buffersize];
    private Rigidbody rigidbody;

    void Start () {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody> ();
    }


    void Update () {
        if (GameManager.Recording == true) {
            Record ();
        } else {
            PlayBack ();
        }

    }

    void PlayBack(){
        rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
        int frame = Time.frameCount % buffersize;
        this.transform.position = playerskeyframe [frame].Position;
        this.transform.rotation = playerskeyframe [frame].rotation;
    }

    void Record(){
        Debug.Log (Time.frameCount % buffersize);
        rigidbody.isKinematic = false;
        int frame = Time.frameCount % buffersize;
        float time = Time.time;
        playerskeyframe [frame] = new MyKeyFrame (time, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation);
    }
}

public struct MyKeyFrame {
    public float frametime;
    public Vector3 Position;
    public Quaternion rotation;

    public MyKeyFrame (float atime,Vector3 apos, Quaternion arotation){
        frametime = atime;
        Position = apos;
        rotation = arotation;
    }

}
```

Edit:- What does not work in my script. Unless frame reaches the buffersize which is 1000 Playback function does not work as expected. That means without completing a loop it does not jump to playback from recording.
Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _"But I have done something wrong."_? What doesn't work on your script?

Comment: I think, until you reach frame 1000 there are some entries in the array which are not set yet and therefore cannot be used to assign the transform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest switching to Queue data type. just add a keyframe each frame you record.
Something gets screwy with your array when you use a % of the frame count. you probably overwrite good valid data like so.

in the record function :

```
keyFrameQueue.Enqueue(new MyKeyFrame 
(
    time, this.transform.position, this.transform.rotation
);
```

and in the playback just put this in the update to happen every frame:

```
if(keyFrameQueue.Count > 0)
{
    MyKeyFrame = keyFrameQueue.Dequeue();
    this.transform.position = MyKeyFrame.Position;
    this.transform.rotation = MyKeyFrame.rotation;
}
```